# Weblogic 12c datasource getting suspended mode

Tags: datasource, weblogic12c

I have a db with 2 ips, 10.x.x.41 and 10.x.x.42, these 2 ips are active and at any time one ip can go down. So In weblogic we have created 2 generic datasources (pool1 and pool2). These 2 datasources are put in one multi datasource with Fail over as Algorithm type. Now application works fine for some time and after some time one of the datasource get in suspended mode and after some time the other one will also get in suspended and application stops. Once it get in suspended mode it is not coming back to running state even if database is up and avaiable.

IS there any specific configuration to bring back the datasource to running mode automatically once it get to suspended mode

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic datasource goes into suspended mode when "test connections on reserve" is set and 2 successive tests fails.

To avoid this from happening set a higher value for "Test Frequency:" and higher value for "Seconds to Trust an Idle Pool Connection:" This should then cover any network glitches you may encounter.

Comment: thanks you for your suggestion, I am trying that and currently i have set "Test Frequency" to 120 sec and "Seconds to Trust an Idle Pool Connection:" to 10 sec. Do you have any comments..?

Comment: Can you please quantify the seconds for "Test Frequency:" and "Seconds to Trust an Idle Pool Connection:".

Comment: we have set "Seconds to Trust an Idle Pool Connection: 300 " "Test Frequency: 120"